# I cannot enable Intel Corporation Wireless 8260 [8086:24f3] (rev 3a)

Tags: networking, 16.04, drivers

Hi I am using Dell Precision-5510 and installed Ubuntu 16.04. I cannot enable my wifi. I also disabled the secure boot which did not help. the result of `sudo lshw -C network` would return:

```
sudo lshw -C network

    *-network DISABLED      
   description: Wireless interface
   product: Wireless 8260
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
   logical name: wlp2s0
   version: 3a
   serial: a4:34:d9:23:1c:84
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=4.8.0-41-generic firmware=21.302800.0 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
   resources: irq:141 memory:ddc00000-ddc01fff
```

`lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A2`

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 8260 [8086:24f3] (rev 3a)
Subsystem: Intel Corporation Wireless 8260 [8086:0050]
Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
```

`dmesg | grep iwl`

```
[    3.618664] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    3.626741] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8000C-24.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.626753] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8000C-23.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.626760] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8000C-22.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.636736] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: loaded firmware version 21.302800.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[    3.660737] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 8260, REV=0x208
[    3.662974] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Disabled
[    3.663620] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Disabled
[    3.869498] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-mvm-rs'
[    3.939057] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0 wlp2s0: renamed from wlan0
```

`uname -rm`

```
4.8.0-41-generic x86_64
```

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-wily linux-firmware`

did not help either.

`rfkill list`

```
0: dell-wifi: Wireless LAN
   Soft blocked: no
   Hard blocked: yes
1: dell-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
2: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Comment: Please add the output of `rfkill list` to your question.

Comment: I added  the output of  `rfkill list`  to the question.

Comment: Try to reset BIOS to defaults. If that does not help, run `sudo modprobe -r dell_wmi`.

Comment: Thank you, it works now. `sudo modprobe -r dell_wmi ` after resetting BIOS was the solution.

Comment: Check if it works after reboot.